# error in sql statement where clause near password

Tags: sql-server

I am getting error in the sql statement.

> ("server= RAJ-PC\SQLEXPRESS; user id=sa; password=as64ws;
>   database=onlineshopping", "select * from customer where userid='" +
>   TextBox1.Text + "', password='" + TextBox2.Text + "'");

I have written this statement to connect to SQL Server. Error is shown in the SQL statement near password.. What is my error???

Comment: Replace `, password` with `and password`. A note of warning, your statement as is is open to an SQL Injection attack. I would advise you to search and read up on parametrized queries.

Comment: Please, use SqlParameters instead of composing your query manually!!

Comment: [Exploits Of A Mom](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Multiple where clauses are combined using AND, not `,`.

```
("server= RAJ-PC\SQLEXPRESS; user id=sa; password=as64ws; database=onlineshopping", "select * from customer where userid='" + TextBox1.Text + "' AND password='" + TextBox2.Text + "'");
```